# DCEF Flash plugin - Last Version DCEF3

Tags: delphi, flash, chromium-embedded, tchromium

I'm using tchromim but there are sites that still need flash installed on windows computer. I need a solution where you do not need to install adobe flash , is that possible?

On the official website CEF:

https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/ReleaseNotes

I noticed that for other languages ​​there are significant updates and Delphi have not found . I am using the following configuration:
[image: My configuration]

The official website pointed this link:

https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3

However, it is well behind the updates on CEF in C#.

Know say what the latest version of the DCEF3 project to Delphi ?

I thank the attention

Comment: Huh? What is your question? Flash is separate software, in case you don't know.

Comment: You need Flash Plugin to view Flash content in a web browser. Either you avoid those website or find a way to have Flash Player installed within your Delphi app (as component?). Use Google or StackOverflow "search Q&A" box for advice on **loading SWF files with Delphi**.

Comment: Live Consulting, Flash is a program installed yes ... The question for those who understand the project required DCEF

Comment: @VC.One 
using compontente tchromium have issues with some sites that send the navagador is outdated or does not have flash , I would circumvent these problems without installing adobe flash , understand? Necessarily in navagador Tchromium the DCEF project. Thank you

Comment: I think you have no idea what role plugin have in the whole embedded Chromium (please consult the websearch). It is not possible to process Flash content w/o Flash Player installed (because of many issues), period.

Comment: @Junior well I dont use Delphi, I code for Flash. I understand what you are saying but a site should never say the browser (navagador?) is outdated. As for Flash plugin component is that DCEF using a **dll** or **ocx** file? I'm thinking maybe you can download the latest official Flash plugin (ActiveX version) and just replace your old files with new ones in the component files directory. If possible.

Comment: Also check **[this help link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/delphichromiumembedded/r4IKa4caVAU)**. Try adding `--enable-system-flash` in your Command Line options. On this site you can test **[if working](http://isflashinstalled.com/)**. It should be version 21 or higher to avoid "plugin is outdated" error. Also maybe you have NPAPI version of Flash but modern browsers want PPAPI version of Flash (latest).

Comment: @VC.One I believe that solve my problem with the link you gave me . Thanks for the information

Comment: Glad it looks to be working for you. Maybe you should put your process as final **Answer** so others with same problem can get help from your solution.